# Download Youtube Videos, Using Pytube.Error url_encoded_fmt_stream_map

Tags: python, pytube

I use Pytube to Download Videos from Youtube.com with this script.

from pytube import YouTube

```
yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
yt.streams.first().download()
```

However when using it and showing the error:**url_encoded_fmt_stream_map**

I have already researched the Internet for other cases but they did not work for me, Want to know if it is possible to Contaminate this Error!.

Comment: yup. not even the simplest tutorial code from the website works... what's ur python version? do you also get `ImportError: No module named request`?

Comment: Version 3-8 Python.The error is due to the lack of installation of the requests library by pip.o error: url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, opinion has to do with the videos.